# aterm not accepting keyboard input

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu

I am running Lubuntu 14.04 and it's default windowmanager. Yesterday I installed aterm with apt-get install, but I can't get aterm working.

**Problem:**

- aterm won't accept keyboard input
- it does accept copy&paste with mouse

I've tried searcing web and these are the closest help I've found:

[FreeBSD forums & xterm](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/3959/)

[StackExchange forums & Ubuntu/aterm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171889/aterm-or-gnome-terminal-window-unresponsive-to-keyboard-events)

The first link wasn't helpful since I can't find such files from my system. Second link was more useful and I tried to make a shell-script to run aterm, but if I run the script from a terminal-window, aterm still won't work and I am not running fluxbox, so I don't know how to edit menus.

Comment: Oh, and I did also try to run aterm with -e /bin/bash and still the same result: no keyboard input

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by installing evilvte and compiling it with transparency as default setting.